# How to add a text on image and save it in flutter?

Tags: image, text, flutter

Which class can be used for loading an image for editing purposes so that i can add a text over it and save it again as PNG/ JPEG to storage

Answer (score 0):

Load the image the file as an Image then call [`Image.toByteData`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Image/toByteData.html)

Edit the byte array

then reimage it to [`decodeImageFromPixels`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/decodeImageFromPixels.html) [issue 11648](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9184)

For storage, it is kinda in flux since you have a few choices like sqlite or file directory

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10495
[Flutter save a network image to local directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49455079/flutter-save-a-network-image-to-local-directory)

I just want to say, image resizing is quite slow in flutter.

https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/issues/55

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26194

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21571#issuecomment-452042242

[Flutter. High GPU load with list of high resolution images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54296173/flutter-high-gpu-load-with-list-of-high-resolution-images)